# Инстаграм: вход в аккаунт

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram-api

Мой код:

```
from instabot import Bot
bot = Bot()
bot.login(name="name",password="password")
```

ошибка:

```
2021-06-29 01:46:16,839 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Никитос/Desktop/forauero.py", line 3, in <module>
    bot.login(name="name",password="password")
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot.py", line 443, in login
    if self.api.login(**args) is False:
TypeError: login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'
```

Я попытался сделать так что бы он зашел в аккаунт,но не работает :(

Comment: Вместо `name` попробуй использовать `username`

Comment: так тоже ошибка

Comment: нет, ошибся, работает

Comment: документацию стоит почитать перед тем, как либу использовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотрите примеры на [github](https://github.com/ohld/igbot/tree/master/examples), если я правильно по версии определил библиотеку)

Используется подобная конструкция к нему

```
bot = Bot()
bot.login(username=username, password=password)
```